# seek the changes of a file

Tags: c#, perforce, p4api.net

i wish detect lines changed of the defferent versions of a file in perforce my problem is that when i tried to get the different versions of the file i get always the last version how can i proceed to get the different versions

```
String password = "*****";
String ws_client = "****";

        Repository rep;
        P4Server ps = new P4Server(conStr, user, password, ws_client);
        Server server = new Server(new ServerAddress(conStr));
        rep = new Repository(server);
        rep.Connection.UserName = user;
        Options options = new Options();

        Console.WriteLine(options.ToString());
        Client c = new Client();

        options["Password"] = password;
        rep.Connection.Client = new Client();
        rep.Connection.Connect(options);
        rep.Connection.Login(password, options);
        Console.WriteLine(rep.ToString());

      string text1="";
        string text2="";
        P4Command cmd = new P4Command(ps);
        string[]cmdargs= new string[1];
        cmdargs[0] = "";
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ps.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(server.ToString());

        // *********************************************************************

        #region mrigla2 using filehistory class

        FileSpec filespecs = new FileSpec(FileSpec.DepotSpec("//obms/Dot-NET/Main/FixDepthSource/SLC_FDS/clsFixEventsSource.vb").DepotPath, Revision.Head);
        Options opt = new Options();
       opt.Add("-m", "");


        IList<FileHistory> filehistories = new List<FileHistory>();
        filehistories = rep.GetFileHistory(new Options(), filespecs);
        if (filehistories != null)
        {
            foreach (FileHistory fh in filehistories)
            {

                string p = fh.DepotPath.Path;

                string dpath = "//obms/Dot-NET/Main/FixDepthSource/SLC_FDS/clsFixEventsSource.vb";
                if (p==dpath)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client name:" + fh.ClientName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Description:" + fh.Description);
                    Console.WriteLine("username:" + fh.UserName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Date:" + fh.Date);

                    Console.WriteLine("changelist:" + fh.ChangelistId);
                    directoriesfile.Filedirectory fsd = Program.getpaths(p, ps); 
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("******************revision:" + fh.Revision+"**********************");
                    if (fh.Revision == 6)
                    {  text1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fsd.localPath); }

                    if (fh.Revision == 5)
                    {text2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fsd.localPath); }

                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    affichcontentFile(fsd.depotPath, ps, fsd.localPath);
                    Console.WriteLine("Action:" + fh.Action);
                }





            }


        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this link to see if it can lend you any direction..? http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/o.ftypes.html

Comment: Was it really necessary to post all that code? How about you only post what isn't working correctly.

Comment: DJ KRAZE i looked to the link . did u mean that i have to do a sync before using files

Comment: I may sound like a stickler, but periods are not underrated.  Your question would be more clear if you used punctuation.

Comment: @Chance can you specify what is not clear

Comment: Where a sentence ends and the next one begins.  I can figure it out, but it takes more effort than you inserting a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the history of the contents of a file, use 'p4 annotate'.

To get the history of a file (but not its contents), use 'p4 filelog'.

To get the differences between two specified versions of a file, use 'p4 diff2'.

Putting together 'p4 filelog' (to figure out which versions correspond to which changes) and 'p4 diff2' (to compute the differences between two versions) will get you much useful information.

Or do what I do: don't do any of these things, and install P4V, and use 'Time Lapse View'. It's a beautiful visual tool that makes exploring a file's history simple.

Comment: does p4 annotate can give me  file version associated to a revision and how can specifie the revision

Comment: i am developping an application using c# and p4api .net

Answer (score 1):

```cs
FileSpec fso = new FileSpec(FileSpec.DepotSpec(fsd.depotPath).DepotPath, Revision.Head);

IList<FileSpec> fsos = new List<FileSpec>();
fsos.Add(fso);

Options opts = new Options();
opts.Add("-a", "");

IList<FileAnnotation> fas = rep.GetFileAnnotations(fsos, opts);

foreach (FileAnnotation fa in fas)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    lines5+= fa.Line;
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
}
```